# Counting the number of distinct keys in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, count, keyword

I have a a dictionary mapping keywords to the repetition of the keyword, but I only want a list of distinct words so I wanted to count the number of keywords. Is there a way to count the number of keywords or is there another way I should look for distinct words?

Comment: The keys in a Python dictionary are already distinct from each other. You can't have the exact some keyword as a key twice in a Python dictionary. Therefore, counting the number of keys is the same as counting the number of distinct keys.

Answer (score 553, accepted):

```
len(yourdict.keys())
```

or just

```
len(yourdict)
```

If you like to count unique words in the file, you could just use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html#module-sets) and do like

```
len(set(open(yourdictfile).read().split()))
```

Comment: I know this post is old, but I was curious. Is this the fastest method? Or: is it *a* reasonably fast method for large dictionaries?

Comment: Both ```len(yourdict.keys())``` and ```len(yourdict)``` are O(1). The latter is slightly faster. See my tests below.

Comment: I'd like to note that you can also go for the values (I know the question didn't ask it) with `len(yourdict.values())`

Answer (score 38):

The number of distinct words (i.e. count of entries in the dictionary) can be found using the `len()` function.

```
> a = {'foo':42, 'bar':69}
> len(a)
2
```

To get all the distinct words (i.e. the keys), use the `.keys()` method.

```
> list(a.keys())
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 13):

Calling `len()` directly on your dictionary works, and is faster than building an iterator, `d.keys()`, and calling `len()` on it, but the speed of either will negligible in comparison to whatever else your program is doing.

```
d = {x: x**2 for x in range(1000)}

len(d)
# 1000

len(d.keys())
# 1000

%timeit len(d)
# 41.9 ns ± 0.244 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit len(d.keys())
# 83.3 ns ± 0.41 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the question is about counting the number of keywords then I would recommend something like:

```
def countoccurrences(store, value):
    try:
        store[value] = store[value] + 1
    except KeyError as e:
        store[value] = 1
    return
```

In the main function, have something that loops through the data and pass the values to the `countoccurrences` function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    store = {}
    list = ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c')
    for data in list:
        countoccurrences(store, data)
    for k, v in store.iteritems():
        print "Key " + k + " has occurred "  + str(v) + " times"
```

The code outputs

```
Key a has occurred 2 times
Key c has occurred 2 times
Key b has occurred 1 times
```

Comment: [PEP 8 naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) dictate that `countoccurrences()` should instead be `count_occurrences()`. Also, if you import [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), there's a much better way to do it: `from collections import Counter; store = Counter(); for data in list: store[list] += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Some modifications were made on posted answer UnderWaterKremlin to make it Python 3 proof. A surprising result is below as an answer.

System specifications:

- Python = 3.7.4,
- [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) = 4.8.0
- 3.6  GHz, 8 cores, 16 GB.

```
import timeit

d = {x: x**2 for x in range(1000)}
#print (d)
print (len(d))
# 1000

print (len(d.keys()))
# 1000

print (timeit.timeit('len({x: x**2 for x in range(1000)})', number=100000))        # 1

print (timeit.timeit('len({x: x**2 for x in range(1000)}.keys())', number=100000)) # 2
```

Result:

1. = 37.0100378
2. = 37.002148899999995

So it seems that `len(d.keys())` is currently faster than just using `len()`.

Answer (score -3):

In order to count the number of keywords in a dictionary:

```
def dict_finder(dict_finders):
    x=input("Enter the thing you want to find: ")
    if x in dict_finders:
        print("Element found")
    else:
        print("Nothing found:")
```