# How to return length of a dictionary to a variable in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

How to return the length of a dictionary to a variable in python?

Comment: What did you try? The answer to this is rather straightforward...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses. You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: ...oops [>> here it is <<](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2212442/8928024).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

var = len(dict)
```

Comment: never name your variables after built-ins or datatypes - like dict, list, set, tuple ... AND ... this ... is a set .... at least if you assing anything to the names `a,b,c` - else is is a `NameError`..

Comment: I fixed the problem.

Comment: @MrGenuis777 The variable is still called `dict` though

Comment: Now I fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Simply just use len():

```
dic = {'val1':0,'val2':0,'val3':0}
length = len(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_var = len(my_dict)`

Gets the number of keys in the dictionary. Equivalent to `len(my_dict.keys())`.