# How to list keys and count with dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm struggling with nested dictionaries. Consider this dictionary of dictionaries:

```
dict=[{'Item 1': {'A': 106,
  'B': 77,
  'C': 46,
  'D': 36},
 'Item 2': {'E': 1141,
  'F': 1065,
  'G': 1020}}]
```

I would like to list the keys and then the count of the nested dictionary keys. So like this:

```
Item 1: 4
Item 2: 3
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `len()` to get the number of keys in a dict: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212433/counting-the-number-of-keywords-in-a-dictionary-in-python

Comment: `for k,v in dict.iteritems(): print(k,':',len(v))` **NOTE** use `.items()` for python 3.x. `iteritems()` is a python 2.x thing.

Comment: or `{i:len(d[0][i]) for i in d[0].keys()}`

Comment: Never call a variable like a [built-in function like dict()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html)

Comment: @pault Thanks. I could get the count of keys for the top level dictionary. len(dict), in this case. I needed the count of keys from the nested dictionaries. That was the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for k,v in lst[0].items():                                                                                                                                                        
    print(k, ':', len(v))
```

Comment: This worked great! And you were first so you get the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One idea:

`[(k, len(v)) for k, v in dict[0].items()]`

Output:

`[('Item 1', 4), ('Item 2', 3)]`

PS. I'd recommend not to name your dictionary `dict` - it is a reserved keyword and by doing so you shadow it.

Comment: This is broken on multiple levels. Your printed output isn't what the OP asked for, and the OP has the dictionary contained within a list so you'll get `AttributeError` trying to use `.items()`

Comment: Copy & paste error. And true about accessing the list, but the list was simply a single element, not adding much. Will fix for consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about "dict." I wasn't using that term in my real file, but good to know so I never do.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a nested dictionary within a list, you must first iterate through the list values. The list values are simply the dictionaries inside of your list. Once loop through the list items you can then loop through the elements of the dictionary. In the code below I looped through each item in the list, and then through the key value pairs to get the output that you are looking for.

```
dictionary = [{'Item 1': {'A': 106,
               'B': 77,
               'C': 46,
               'D': 36},
               'Item 2': {'E': 1141,
               'F': 1065,
               'G': 1020}}]

for item in dictionary:
      for key, value in item.items():
             print('{}:{}'.format(key, len(value)))
```

And here is your output:

```
Item 1:4
Item 2:3
```